# How to install a specific version of python with pip, venv, and distutils on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, cython, python-venv

I've recently had to debug a cython library for a specific version of python on ubuntu and I needed python, venv, distutils, cython, pip, a compiler, and a text editor.  I had to go fishing around the web for instructions on how to do this, so I'm asking this question to answer with what I did.

I googled it and found instructions in one place for pip, another place for venv, another place for compilers.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out on ubuntu 20 in docker (I was running as root).  If you are not running as root - this answer won't help you.

```
# update the package manager
apt-get update

# install git, C/C++ compiler and a text editor (I prefer vim)
apt install -y git software-properties-common curl build-essential vim

# add package source for python distributions
add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

# install specific version of python with venv and distutils
apt install -y python3.9 python3.9-distutils python3.9-venv

# get pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3.9 get-pip.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the version of python that you want, i recommend use dead-sneak, https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/install+python+3.7+from+source+in+ubuntu+linux.

Later set your python version in the venv, something like "virtualenv venv --python=python{python version}" or "python{python version} -m venv venv"